# a mouse hand on hover when a tag binded with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

How do I get the `a` tag `click- binded` with knockout to show a mouse hand on hover?

I bind a click to my `a` tag using knockout as follows:

```
<li data-bind="visible: HasPrevious">
    <a aria-label="Previous" data-bind="click: GoToPrevious">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Everything works, but the problem is on mouse hover the I don't get the famous mouse hand.

If I replace with the normal `href` I get the hand on hover? Is there a way to maintain that behavior while binding with knockoutjs?

Comment: Probably best to add an empty `href`, but a quick & dirty hack is to style it using css: `a[data-bind*="click:"] { cursor: pointer; }` Note that this will have some false positives, e.g. `<a data-bind="text: 'click:me'"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

you should still have the `href` attribute on your `a` element, knockout will make it so that the # isn't treated like an anchor element because of its click binding doing something like Event.stopPropagation(), so use it like so

`<a href="#" data-bind="click: GoToPrevious">`

```html
<a>foo</a>
<a href="#">bar</a>
```